# Why does the limit of $\lim_{x \to \infty} \arcsin \left(\frac{x+1}{x}\right)$ not exist?

Tags: calculus, limits

Why does this this limit not exist?

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \arcsin \left({x+1\over x}\right)$$

According to me on dividing both the numerator and the denominator by $x$ and then putting $ x = \infty $ we should get  $ \arcsin (1) $ which is equal to $ \frac{\pi} 2$ . Where am I wrong?

Comment: The expression  $\lim_{x \to \infty} \arcsin \left({x+1\over x}\right)$  
is meaningless since $\frac{x+1}{x} >1$.

Comment: Note that if $\arcsin$ is considered a function from $\Bbb C \to \Bbb C$, then the function is defined for arguments $> 1$, and the limit does exist. But whether it is $\pi/2$ depends on which branch of the $\arcsin$ function you choose.

Comment: Before you take the limit, ask yourself: What is the domain of your function? Conclusion?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The $\arcsin$ function is only defined on the domain $-1 \le x \le 1$. Since the input ${x+1 \over x} > 1 \,\forall x > 0$, the limit does not exist.

Comment: I wouldn't say that the limit doesn't exist, maybe it is more correct to say that the expression is not well-defined for x>0.

Comment: I prefer use the expression the limit doesn't exist when the expression is well defined but for example the function oscillates.

Comment: @gimusi I guess that wording is better since we're approaching the function from the right side which doesn't exist.

Comment: It is of course a matter of convention and definition. I use the term "doesn't exist" for limit as for example $\lim_{x\to \infty} \sin x$ since the expression is well defined. In this case of that OP we can't even apply the definition of limit since the expression in not well-defined.

Comment: It is perfectly reasonable to say that the limit does not exist, since, well, no such limit exists.  I think that reserving the phrase "does not exist" for only oscillatory functions is somewhat idiosyncratic.

Answer (score 23):

Because $\frac{x+1}{x}>1$ for $x>0$, and $\arcsin{y}$ is not defined for $y>1$.

On the other hand, the limit as $x \to -\infty$ does exist, since $-1<\frac{x+1}{x}<1$ for sufficiently large negative $x$, and is $\pi/2$.

Comment: Most complete answer, IMHO.

Answer (score 4):

The limit does not exist, because $\frac{x+1}{x}$ approaches $1$ from the right, where $\arcsin(x)$ is not defined.

Answer (score 2):

> ...on dividing both the numerator and the denominator by x and then putting $x=\infty$...

if you could just do that, then there wouldn't really be a need for ever using limits. $\infty$ is not a number (in standard analysis, that is), so you can't “put $x=\infty$”.

Instead, the whole idea of the limit is to put in ever larger *finite* values for $x$ and still get a result that's not only always finite, but actually *converges* towards some point (which we then call the limit). This does work for
$$
  \lim_{x\to\infty} \arcsin\Bigl(\underbrace{\frac{x}{x+1}}_{y}\Bigr)
$$
because here, you always have $0<y<1$, so can always find a solution to $y = \sin t$, and because $y$ goes asymptotically to $1$, this<sup>†</sup> converges to a single point:

[image: Convergent limit]

But it doesn't at all work for the limit you're asking about, because here $y>1$ for a finite $x$, and that means you don't actually ever get a solution at all. Thus there also can't be a limit.

[image: Non-existant limit]

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>It only converges if you actually choose always *the same* solution, such as *always the absolute-smallest one*, which is what the $ⅹcsin$ function yields.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You are wrong to assume that

$$\lim_{x\to a} f(x)=f(\lim_{x\to a}x).$$

You have a perfect counter-example before you.

Comment: This downvote is undue. I do answer the question "Where am I wrong".